# NullPointerException while using checkstyle in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, checkstyle, maven-checkstyle-plugin

I was using the static analysis tool checkstyle in my Jenkins server to run static analysis on a private maven project after the build. I have done configurations in the Post Build setup of Jenkins.

There is a checkstyle config file which is formatted appropriately called **csc_checkstyle.xml** which is set in the Post-Build section of Jenkins We have added the checkstyle plugin and warnings next gen to Jenkins. The checkstyle config file is set properly.

When the build runs and triggers this plugin we get the following error :

```
[CheckStyle] [ERROR] Parsing of file  '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/iTrust/iTrust2/src/test/resources/reporting/csc_checkstyle.xml' failed due to an exception:
[CheckStyle] [ERROR] java.lang.NullPointerException
[CheckStyle] [ERROR] [wrapped] java.net.MalformedURLException
[CheckStyle] [ERROR] at java.net.URL.(URL.java:627)
[CheckStyle] [ERROR] at java.net.URL.(URL.java:490)
[CheckStyle] [ERROR] at java.net.URL.(URL.java:439)
[CheckStyle] [ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:620)
[CheckStyle] [ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1304)
[CheckStyle] [ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1270)
[CheckStyle] [ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(XMLDTDScannerImpl.java:264)
[CheckStyle] [ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1161)
[CheckStyle] [ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1045)
[CheckStyle] [ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:959)
[CheckStyle] [ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
[CheckStyle] [ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
[CheckStyle] [ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
[CheckStyle] [ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
[CheckStyle] [ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
[CheckStyle] [ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
[CheckStyle] [ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
[CheckStyle] [ERROR] at org.apache.commons.digester3.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1642)
[CheckStyle] [ERROR] at org.apache.commons.digester3.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1745)
[CheckStyle] [ERROR] at edu.hm.hafner.analysis.parser.checkstyle.CheckStyleParser.parse(CheckStyleParser.java:47)
[CheckStyle] [ERROR] [wrapped] edu.hm.hafner.analysis.ParsingException: Exception occurred during parsing: null
[CheckStyle] [ERROR] at edu.hm.hafner.analysis.parser.checkstyle.CheckStyleParser.parse(CheckStyleParser.java:55)
[CheckStyle] [ERROR] at io.jenkins.plugins.analysis.core.model.FilesScanner.aggregateIssuesOfFile(FilesScanner.java:98)
[CheckStyle] [ERROR] at io.jenkins.plugins.analysis.core.model.FilesScanner.scanFiles(FilesScanner.java:82)
[CheckStyle] [ERROR] at io.jenkins.plugins.analysis.core.model.FilesScanner.invoke(FilesScanner.java:65)
[CheckStyle] [ERROR] at io.jenkins.plugins.analysis.core.model.FilesScanner.invoke(FilesScanner.java:28)
[CheckStyle] [ERROR] at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1078)
[CheckStyle] [ERROR] at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1061)
[CheckStyle] [ERROR] at io.jenkins.plugins.analysis.core.model.ReportScanningTool.scanInWorkspace(ReportScanningTool.java:126)
[CheckStyle] [ERROR] at io.jenkins.plugins.analysis.core.model.ReportScanningTool.scan(ReportScanningTool.java:108)
[CheckStyle] [ERROR] at io.jenkins.plugins.analysis.core.steps.IssuesScanner.scan(IssuesScanner.java:66)
[CheckStyle] [ERROR] at io.jenkins.plugins.analysis.core.steps.IssuesRecorder.scanWithTool(IssuesRecorder.java:578)
[CheckStyle] [ERROR] at io.jenkins.plugins.analysis.core.steps.IssuesRecorder.record(IssuesRecorder.java:546)
[CheckStyle] [ERROR] at io.jenkins.plugins.analysis.core.steps.IssuesRecorder.perform(IssuesRecorder.java:514)
[CheckStyle] [ERROR] at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:81)
[CheckStyle] [ERROR] at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
[CheckStyle] [ERROR] at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
[CheckStyle] [ERROR] at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
[CheckStyle] [ERROR] at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
[CheckStyle] [ERROR] at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
[CheckStyle] [ERROR] at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1835)
[CheckStyle] [ERROR] at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
[CheckStyle] [ERROR] at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
[CheckStyle] [ERROR] at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
```

The thing to note here is it is taking the path of the config file `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/iTrust/iTrust2/src/test/resources/reporting/csc_checkstyle.xml` is correct.

Does anyone have any idea why a `NullPointerException` is being thrown? The formatting of the file also seems to be correct.

The `csc_checkstyle.xml` is  the raw version of [Google default checkstyle config](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml)

Comment: NPE is probably the result of the MalformedURLException which is from parsing some XML document. I would look there first. If config works directly with checkstyle jar outside jenkins, then it is something in jenkins.

Comment: Although you state that the formatting of **csc_checkstyle.xml** _"seems to be correct"_, the issue does seem related to its content. Can you update your post to show that file?

Comment: I have added a link to the config file. It is basically just the raw version I have just copy pasted the google default checkstyle config into a new file and committed into my repo by the name of csc_checkstyle.xml

Comment: Can you confirm the exact same config used outside of jenkins works with the same checkstyle you are using in jenkins? Also if you are using the google config, I would use the one packaged with the version of checkstyle you are using and not one copied from the master branch.